# Efficiently extend 8-bit numbers to 12-bits in a single arm neon register

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I have 4 bytes loaded in a neon register. How can I efficiently convert that to 12-bit e.g. I need to insert 4 zero bits after the first byte, 8 zero bits after the second and so on. For example, if I had these 4 bytes in hex:

> 01 02 03 04

[It would end up with this in hex](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4141c6081b2161d4):

> 01 20 00 03 40

Same operation expressed as a simple c-function that operates on a 32-bit variable that represents the 4 input bytes:

```
uint64_t expand12(uint32_t i)
{
    uint64_t r = (i & 0xFF);
    r |= ((i & 0x0000ff00) << 4); // shift second byte by 4 bits
    r |= ((i & 0x00ff0000) << 8); // shift third byte by 8 bits
    r |= (((uint64_t)(i & 0xff000000)) << 12); // 4th by 12
    return r;
}
```

So, if I have these bytes in a `uint8x8_t` neon register, what would be a good way to implement that same operation in neon so that same register would end up with these shifted values?

Note, that all four bytes have zeroes in top 4 bits if that helps in any way.

**Update:**
In my case I have 4 uint16x8_t registers and for each one I need to calculate sum of all lanes (`vaddv_u16`), then perform `vclz_u16` on that sum and then combine these four sums in a neon register placing them 12-bit apart:

```
uint64_t compute(uint16x8_t a, uint16x8_t b, uint16x8_t c, uint16x8_t d)
{
    u16 a0 = clz(vaddv(a));
    u16 b0 = clz(vaddv(b));
    u16 c0 = clz(vaddv(c));
    u16 d0 = clz(vaddv(d));
    return (a0 << 36) | (b0 << 24) | (c0 << 12) | (d0);
}
```

Note, that this is pseudo code and I need the result in neon register.

In case if that matters, in my code I have a function that finds indices of max elements in 4 uint16x8_t registers. In that function these four registers are `vand`ed with max element duplicated over all lanes and then the result was `vorr`ed with bitmask `{1<<15, 1<<14, ... 1<<0}`; Then, I do pairwise add of all the lanes and clz of that gives me the index of max element of each register. All of that I need to interleave  with extra 4 zero-bits inserted between elements and stored to a neon register. Example in C:

```
void compute(uint16_t *src, uint64_t* dst)
{
    uint64_t x[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i, src+=16)
    {
        int max = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
        {
            if (src[j] > src[max])
                max = j;
        }
        x[i] = max;
    }
    *dst = (x[0] << 36) | (x[1] << 24) | (x[2] << 12) | (x[3]);
}
```

This function is part of large function that does this computation millions of times in a loop and results of this function are used and have to be in neon register. Treat it as pseudo code that describes the algorithm, if it's not clear what that means: it means that only algorithm matters, there is no loads or stores that need to be optimized

Comment: On x86-64 with BMI2, you could do 32->48 bits with a scalar [`pdep`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html), 1 uop on Intel but slow on current AMD.  On ARM with NEON I'm thinking we probably need byte shuffles + per-element shifts, maybe with variable-count shifts?  Perhaps shuffle / shift / shuffle to get zeros in the top 4 bits of the relevant bytes?

Comment: maybe there is something similar with bit-shift insert that Jake suggested in one of other questions. Probably I can do something similar. I'll update question with relevant info

Comment: How does `01 02 03 04` become `01 20 00 03 40` again? I don't see it from your code snippet, which is supposed to do something like: `0x01` -> `0x01`, `0x02` -> `0x20`, `0x03` -> `0x0300`, `0x04` -> `0x4000`. I guess what you meant was `01 20 00 03 00 40`? And what does "convert that to 12-bit" mean? Last four bits shifted by 12 gives a 16-bit value.

Comment: Think about it as inserting 4-zero bits between the four bytes. [Run the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4141c6081b2161d4) to see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think out of the box. Don't stick to the data type and bit width.

`uint32_t` is nothing else than an array of 4 `uint8_t` which you can easily spread through `vld4` on-the-fly while loading.

The problem gets much more manageable thereby.

---

```
void foo(uint32_t *pDst, uint32_t *pSrc, uint32_t length)
{
    length >>= 4;
    int i;
    uint8x16x4_t in, out;
    uint8x16_t temp0, temp1, temp2;

    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        in = vld4q_u8(pSrc);
        pSrc += 16;

        temp0 = in.val[1] << 4;
        temp1 = in.val[3] << 4;
        temp1 += in.val[1] >> 4;

        out.val[0] = in.val[0] | temp0;
        out.val[1] = in.val[2] | temp1;
        out.val[2] = in.val[3] >> 4;
        out.val[3] = vdupq_n_u8(0);

        vst4q_u8(pDst, out);
        pDst += 16;
    }
}
```

---

Note that I omitted the residual dealing, and it would run much faster if you unroll deeper.

More importantly, I'd write this function in assembly without thinking twice, because I don't think that the compiler would manage the registers so cleverly that `out.val[3]` gets initialized by zero only once outside the loop.

And I also doubt that `temp1 += in.val[1] >> 4;` would translate to `vsra` because of the instruction's nature of non-separate target operand. Who knows?

Compilers suck.

---

Update: Ok, here are codes that shall meet your needs, written in assembly, for both architectures.

---

aarch32

```
vtrn.16     q0, q1
vtrn.16     q2, q3
vtrn.32     q0, q2
vtrn.32     q1, q3

vadd.u16    q0, q1, q0
vadd.u16    q2, q3, q2

adr     r12, shift_table

vadd.u16    q0, q2, q0

vld1.64     {q3}, [r12]


vadd.u16    d0, d1, d0
vclz.u16    d0, d0          // d0 contains the leading zeros

vmovl.u16   q0, d0

vshl.u32    q1, q0, q3

vpadal.u32  d3, d2          // d3 contains the final result


.balign 8
shift_table:
    .dc.b   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 // 0, 12, 24, 4
```

---

aarch64

```
trn1        v16.8h, v0.8h, v1.8h
trn1        v18.8h, v2.8h, v3.8h
trn2        v17.8h, v0.8h, v1.8h
trn2        v19.8h, v2.8h, v3.8h

trn2        v0.4s, v18.4s, v16.4s
trn1        v1.4s, v18.4s, v16.4s
trn2        v2.4s, v19.4s, v17.4s
trn1        v3.4s, v19.4s, v17.4s

add         v0.8h, v1.8h, v0.8h
add         v2.8h, v3.8h, v2.8h

adr     x16, shift_table

add         v0.8h, v2.8h, v0.8h

ld1         {v3.2d}, [x16]

mov         v1.d[0], v0.d[1]

add         v0.4h, v1.4h, v0.4h

clz         v0.4h, v0.4h                // v0 contains the leading zeros

uxtl        v0.4s, v0.4h

ushl        v0.4s, v0.4s, v3.4s

mov         v1.d[0], v0.d[1]

uadalp      v1.1d, v0.2s                // v1 contains the final result


.balign 8
shift_table:
.dc.b   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 // 0, 12, 24, 4
```

** You may have to change `.dc.b` to `.byte` in Clang

Comment: Even 5 year old gcc at `-O1` unrolls the loop and [moves out](https://godbolt.org/g/GZLDGP) `out.val[3] = vdupq_n_u8(0);`

Comment: compilers are much smarter than you think. Even when neon intrinsics were complete garbage 10 years ago they would still do this basic piece well. off course `out.val[3]` [will be inited once](https://godbolt.org/g/R2mAkv) outside of the loop. `temp1 += in.val[1] >> 4` didn't translate to `vsra`, but then `vsra` might not necessarily be better: compiler always know all the data dependencies and opcode timings and can optimize it well especially when a function is large.

Comment: Basically, input to the function was already interleaved and made to be outside of the box if that even matters.

Comment: @Pavel Your question updates are really getting tedious. As it seems, your last two questions were actually a single one. And who knows what comes next? Why didn't you ask for an algorithm doing both from the beginning? Why don't you ever mention the total problem size? Even my customers who pay me a few grands for a single function aren't this inconsiderate.

Comment: Yes, I agree, sorry for that :) I posted minimal questions when I stumbled on the actual issue of merging 4 results and asked just that part.